# cannot autostart snap on Rpi4 bullseye

Tags: linux, boot-issues, debian

I have a pi with Debian bullseye. I have a snap - `zwave-js-ui`. The snap works fine (`sudo snap start zwave-js-ui`); however I would like it to start on boot. The `enable` appears to be unsuccessful:

```
sudo snap enable zwave-js-ui
```

[image: screenshot from console commands]

What to do?

Comment: I actually changed the installation of this app to the `npm` version, as described here: https://zwave-js.github.io/zwave-js-ui/#/getting-started/other-methods?id=npm, then made a systemd service. I'll add the steps as an answer soon, although I'm not sure it's an answer, more a totally different way of using the app.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with `snap`s, but if it's run from the CLI, I imagine that you could start it at boot using `cron`, or a unit file under `systemd`. `cron` is easier, so try this:

##### 1. Open `root`'s `crontab` for editing :

```bash
sudo crontab -e
```

This should open the `root crontab` in your default editor.

##### 2. Enter this line at the bottom of the file:

```
@reboot sleep 10; /full/path/to/snap start zwave-js-ui >> /home/pi/snap.log 2>&1
```

Note that *"/full/path/to/"* means that you must replace this string with the **actual path to the `snap` executable**.

The *redirects* (`>>` & `2>&1` means to write any output from the program to the designated file. I.e. if `/home/pi` doesn't exist, use a folder that does.